# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when trying to get document through Rest call

Tags: java, heap-memory, jersey-client

I am making a web service call using the following lines of code but I am getting OutOfMemoryError for larger files.

I can't increase the heap size so just wanted to know if there is something wrong with the code or is there a more efficient way for the purpose.

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                .get(ClientResponse.class);
        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus());
        }
        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(output.getBytes());
```

Following is the error log:

```
The WebLogic Server encountered a critical failure
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:596)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:190)
at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.readFromAsString(ReaderWriter.java:172)
at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.readFromAsString(ReaderWriter.java:157)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.readFromAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:114)
at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.readFrom(StringProvider.java:73)
at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.readFrom(StringProvider.java:58)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:634)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:586)
at net.deldot.util.DocumentInfoFromProjectPortal.getDocument(Unknown Source)
at net.deldot.servlet.publicsite.command.ProjectDocumentCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
at net.deldot.servlet.CommandExecutorServlet.internalProcessHttpRequest(Unknown Source)
at net.deldot.servlet.CommandExecutorServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3679)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
Reason: There is a panic condition in the server. The server is configured to exit on panic
```

Also, for some files I am getting OOM for decoding files. The log is

```
The WebLogic Server encountered a critical failure
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:350)
at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:941)
at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils.getBytes(StringUtils.java:96)
at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(StringUtils.java:235)
at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.BaseNCodec.decode(BaseNCodec.java:394)
at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(Base64.java:692)
at net.deldot.util.DocumentInfoFromProject.getDocument(Unknown Source)
at net.deldot.servlet.publicsite.command.ProjectDocumentCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
at net.deldot.servlet.CommandExecutorServlet.internalProcessHttpRequest(Unknown Source)
at net.deldot.servlet.CommandExecutorServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3679)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
Reason: There is a panic condition in the server. The server is configured to exit on panic
```

Comment: Unless the service you're calling can send the content in parts or not Base64 encode the data you need more memory.  Even if you don't Base64 encode you could still run out.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to decode everything in memory (e.g. because you don't have enough memory) try to use a stream-oriented approach.

E.g. you could try to use [Base64.Decoder#wrap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html#wrap(java.io.InputStream)).

Try (untested):

```
   Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
   try (InputStream is = decoder.wrap(response.getEntity(InputStream .class))) {
        //process stream
   }
```

From there you could write the content to a db stream or a response stream etc. without ever loading the whole content to memory at once.